# How to convert char ** to char * in C++

Tags: visual-c++

I am knot shure how to convret  `char **` to `char *` in C++.

```
void Text(char **Message)
{ 
 char* result = (char*)&Message; // It doesnt work :(
}
```

Any clue?

Comment: `char* result = *Message;`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the correct answer

```
int main()
{
    char  var = 'A';
    char  *ptr;
    char  **pptr;

    // take the address of var
    ptr = &var;

    // take the address of ptr using address of operator &
    pptr = &ptr;

    // take the value using pptr
    cout << "Value of var :" << var << endl;
    cout << "Value available at *ptr :" << *ptr << endl;
    cout << "Value available at **pptr :" << **pptr << endl;

    Text(pptr);

    return 0;
}

void Text(char **Message)
{
    char  *msg = *Message;
    Print(msg);
}

void Print(char * data)
{
cout << "char is :" << *data << endl; // It gives A

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I created a program to help you:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void Text(char **Message, int length)
{ 
    while (length > 0) {
        char* result = *(Message++);
        length--;

        cout << result << endl;
    }
}

void main()
{
    char *names[] = {
        "John", "Mona",
        "Lisa", "Frank"
    };

    Text(names, 4);
}
```

To dereference your pointer, you need only use `*Message`.

Comment: Hi! How we can get length of char **Message on fly? Basically I need toconvert entire char **Message...

Comment: Use [strlen](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strlen/) to get the length of a string.

Comment: It's unclear what `Message` represents.  Is it a collection of `char*`?  Is it the address of a `char*` meant to be changed as an output argument?  `strlen` can be used to get the length of a null-terminated `char*`, but first you have to know what the data you're working with actually means.